# Is there a good way of referring to a collection of exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a database access layer that I maintain.  There are some operations that can raise a variety of exceptions, some of them local to the library and some of them builtins or from other libraries.  Is there a good way to declare a collection of them so that users of the library can refer to them easily?

I've considered doing this:

```
DatabaseAccessError = (
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
    http.client.IncompleteRead,
    ConnectionRefusedError,
    DatabaseDoesNotExistError
)
```

This then means that someone can:

```
try:
    ...
except DatabaseAccessError:
    ...
```

But it causes a mess if they want to handle anything else at the same time:

```
try:
    ...
except DatabaseAccessError + (KeyboardInterrupt,):
    ...
```

The other thing I've considered is that I could go around the library and carefully catch all these exceptions anywhere they are raised and then `raise DatabaseAccessError from e`.  But I'm lazy and this looks error-prone.  Isn't there a better way?

The motivation here is that I've noticed that users of my database access layer generally manage to catch *some* of these exceptions but are far from reliable in catching all of them.  It's never clear whether this is intentional (they want some of the exceptions to bubble up - I think this is unlikely but maybe) or if they just haven't thought through their exception handling well enough (and, to be fair, the exception list is not very well documented).

Comment: I don't see why the multiple inheritance solution would not be acceptable. Perhaps also google "mixin".

Comment: @tripleee - thinking about it some more, the multiple inheritance doesn't achieve the objective; something raising `http.client.IncompleteRead` will not hit a handler with `except DatabaseAccessError`.  I'll update the question.  Mixins don't help here.

Comment: @Tom Your example doesn't make much sense. Why should `KeyboardInterrupt` (or whatever) be handled in the same except clause as the DB exceptions? The standard idiom is to use separate except clauses for conceptually different groups. Lumping disparate exception classes together very quickly becomes equivalent to just catching `Exception` (or even `BaseException`). If all the users want is a generic catch-all without class-specific handling, they don't need your DB group. Custom exception classes (or groups) should be primarily designed for code that can constructively handle them.

Comment: @ekhumoro It's an example without having to regurgitate too much of the actual code for context.  Obviously you wouldn't actually do that.

Comment: @Tom That clearly doesn't affect any of the points I made. Substitute `KeyboardInterrupt` with whatever you like. As it stands, you haven't provided a coherent use-case, nor explained why you can't simply use multiple except clauses. And what do you expect users to do with `DatabaseAccessError`, if not handle the *specific* group of exceptions it encompasses? If it already includes all the relevant classes, it makes no sense for users to add anything else to it.

Comment: @Tom PS: also note that even if users do need a catch-all handler that includes the DB exceptions, they can simply do e.g. `except (*DatabaseAccessError, WhateverError):`, which is only one extra character.

Comment: @ekhumoro - yes, `except (*DatabaseAccessError, WhateverError):` is where I've ended up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct design there is to take advantage of inheritance, so that all exceptions that matter in a case are grouped as subclasses of the catch all exception.

Note that this design is natural for "plain" exceptions, and even Python's stdlib uses it (OSError being a superclass for a pletora of more specific file access and networking errors, for example)

But in your case, your Exceptions appearing to have different hierarchies, that would not work straightforaward. When starting this answer, I was intending to suggest you to use multiple-inheritance - that would work for all of *your* exceptions, and an ExceptionMixin could effectivelly work as a tag.

That is, let's suppose you'd want a `MyTimeoutError` to be at same time a `DatabaseAccessError` and a `NetworkError`:

it could be declared as both with

`class MyTimeoutError(DatabaseError, NetworkError): pass`

But, of course, you can't change Python's existing `TimeoutError` to be a subclass of those -- or can you?

First: at this point the "correct way" is the hard way, sorry, there is no escape: you have to catch the foregin exceptions in your code, and normalize then by re-raising an exception with a well defined, single inheritance, descent. Sorry <-  this is the correct way to go, period!

Then going back to the  "or can you?" part: Python has a mechanism of "Virtual Subclassing" which enables you to consider, for certin purposes, classes unrelated to your code at all as instances, or subclasses of classes under your control.

But I am unsure if this mechanism will work with the `except` statement at all.

The easiest way to do this is to create a class inheriting from `abc.ABC`, and then using its `register` method to register unrelated classes that are to be treated as subclasses. Let's see were that take us:  [/me switches to interactive terminal]

```
In [1]: import abc

In [2]: class DatabaseError(Exception, abc.ABC): pass

In [3]: # so far so good!

In [4]: DatabaseError.register(TimeoutError)
Out[4]: TimeoutError

In [5]: issubclass(TimeoutError, DatabaseError)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: try:
   ...:     raise TimeoutError("time exceeded")
   ...: except DatabaseError:
   ...:     print("Hahaha: it works")
   ...: except TimeoutError:
   ...:     print("nahh, it didn't work")
   ...: 
nahh, it didn't work
```

So, sorry for that. this is not "one of the ways" virtual subclassing can help.